# Coroutines: What is the difference between lifecycleScope and viewModelScope?

Tags: android, asynchronous, viewmodel, kotlin-coroutines, lifecycle

Pretty much the title-not sure when I should use one versus the other if the choice exists. Additionally, what are some precautions/best practices when using a coroutine to execute requests using retrofit2 API?

Comment: In short, lifecycleScope lives as long as the lifecycleOwner lives; the viewModelScope lives as long as the viewModel lives; the latter lives long obviously.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the difference between lifecycleScope and viewModelScope?

[ViewModelScope](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModel#(androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel).viewModelScope()) lasts until the ViewModel is cleared.

[LifecycleCoroutineScope](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/LifecycleCoroutineScope) lasts until the Lifecycle (i.e., Fragment or Activity) is destroyed.

> not sure when I should use one versus the other if the choice exists

What is the work you're doing? Is it tied to the ViewModel's lifetime or the view's?
A network request for example would go in the ViewModel to keep the request going even if the Activity is killed. Any coroutine that needs to access the view hierarchy (which will not be valid after the view is destroyed) would go in the lifecycle scope.

> Additionally, what are some precautions/best practices when using a coroutine to execute requests using retrofit2 API?

This is a vague and open-ended question unrelated to your main question.